# Regarding the boundedness of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I have the following problem proving the next statement:

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a real-valued sequence if $$|x_n|^2\leq C|x_n|+C,$$ then $\{x_n\}$ is bounded. Where $C$ is a positive constant.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: a monic quadratic can be negative only between its two real roots. Now use that for $\,|x_n|^2 - C |x_n| - C \le 0\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $$|x_n|^2 \le C|x_n| + C$$
you get
$$\left(|x_n| - \frac{C}{2} \right)^2 \le C + \frac{C^2}{4}$$
by simply carrying $C|x_n|$ to the left side of the inequality, and adding $\frac{C^2}{4}$ on both sides. This yields
$$\left||x_n| - \frac{C}{2}\right| \le \sqrt{C + \frac{C^2}{4}}$$
Therefore,
$$|x_n| = ||x_n|| \le \left||x_n| - \frac{C}{2}\right| + \frac{C}{2} \le \frac{C}{2}+\sqrt{C + \frac{C^2}{4}}$$
i.e. $$|x_n| \le \frac{C}{2}+\sqrt{C + \frac{C^2}{4}}$$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, i.e. $\{x_n\}$ is *bounded*.

Answer (score 0):

You have $C \ge \frac{|x_n|^2}{|x_n| + 1}$. Suppose $|x_n|$ is unbounded. How does the right-hand side behave as $|x_n|$ gets larger and larger?